# What is the meaning of the Fourier Transform of the electric field of a well guided mode in a dielectric waveguide?

Tags: electric-fields, simulations, fourier-transform, waveguide

I have been studying waveguiding in dielectrics for a while now; however, I cannot understand the meaning of the Fourier transformed electric field. I will first give some background information.

Using Maxwell's Equations and the boundary conditions of a given waveguide structure (rectangular waveguide, for example), we can derive the characteristic equations for the TE and TM polarizations for such a waveguide as a function of free space wavelength, thickness of the waveguide, and the refractive indices of adjacent media ($n_{cover}$, $n_{film}$, $n_{substrate}$). Using those equations, we can define a finite set of guided mode propagation constants ($\beta_{mp}$) for a given free space wavenumber, $k_0$, mode, $m$, and polarization, $p$.

[image: planar waveguide]

The working wavenumber in the waveguide is defined as $k = n_f k_0 = \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda_0}n_f$. This indicates that in a media with a refractive index, $n_i > 1$, the wavelength decreases and thereby the wavenumber increase as the index increases, yet frequency is unchanged in all media.

As far as I understand, the propagation constant for a given guided mode is the wavenumber in the direction of propagation along the waveguide. Thus, it is defined as $\beta = k cos(\theta) = n_f k_0 cos(\theta) = n_{eff} k_0$, where $\theta$ is defined as the angle of $k$ from the direction of propagation.

Thus, for a continuous wave(CW), for a given frequency, $k_0$ should be fixed and thereby for a given mode, $\beta$ should also be fixed.

In MEEP, I completed a 2D FDTD CW simulation for a planar waveguide for a single frequency whose wavelength is $\lambda_0 = 1550nm$. I took a slice of the data for the electric field at a given time. I cropped this dated to include five wavelengths of data, ensuring that the portion included the tails of the evanescent field. Using Matlab, I Fourier transformed the electric field from this section and I then plotted the real part of it.

[image: FFT and E Field]

Herein lies my dilemma: In the FFT field, instead of finding two points corresponding to the propagation constants, as I expected, I found a distribution of points on two parallel lines.

Could someone please help me to understand the meaning of this Fourier transform? Thank you!

Comment: A point in the Fourier spectrum corresponds to a wave of infinite length, which you don't have. In one direction you have a single cycle and in the other direction you have six cycles, neither of which will give a sharply defined spectrum.

Comment: @CuriousOne, thank you for your response. That really helps to clarify this. So, extending the waveguide with the field propagating further and further should then sharpen the two lines to more closely approximate points?

Comment: You have a couple of options: you make the waveguide longer, which is really just a repetition of the same solution over and over, again, or, if there is an integer number of waves in the dataset, you can use a short discrete Fourier transform, which collects all the energy into a small number of discrete spectral points. I think you may want to read a few textbook chapters on the properties of these transforms and how one can make use of such periodic conditions. Some of the best illustrated resources can be found in the DSP and digital communications literature.

Comment: @CuriousOne, again thank you for your elucidation. I'll check the literature you mentioned.